# redirect without page reload

Tags: php, xhtml

I want to redirect error message to index page so i wrote the following code:

```
 $message="Bad answer, go back to page!";
    header("location:index.php?message=".$message);
```

this code in process page, and i'm fetching data in index.php page like:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['message'])) {
           $message=$_GET['message'];?>
           <?php echo $message; ?></iframe>
    }
     else { echo ""; }
   ?>
```

i tried to display message in iframe....but i couldn't succeed.

Comment: y u want to show it in a iframe? any specific reason if not so then try using span or div.

Comment: ya if there is way can u suggest by code...

Answer (score 0):

Your echoing the iFrame tags incompletely/incorrectly. Try this

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['message'])) {
           $message=$_GET['message'];
           echo '<iframe>'.$message.'</iframe>';
    }
     else { echo ""; }
?>
```

Comment: i need to show my redirected message in my div/iframe block that to without clearing the form fields....

Comment: yeah, the above fixed one of the issues. You weren't showing an iFrame at all before. I'll edit in a second to fix the other problem.

Comment: I was in the middle of testing a solution but my keyboard died and I'm typing from my touchpad now. Is it a requirement to not use javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for ur strain to get connected using touchpad. Here no need of javascript or other. its pure php task.

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about DOM manipulation (without needing to refresh the page), you should know the best, most elegant way is to do that with Jquery / Ajax / PHP.

1. Use **[$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get)** or **[$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post)** to send data to PHP and get the returned data (this case : `Bad answer, go back to page!`)
2. Get your `<div>` or `<iframe>` element and load the returned data inside of your selected element with Jquery.

I don't know if you are willing to do some changes. If you are willing to do more changes, please drop a comment so I will give you a code example about it.

**Some Information you must know;**

**[$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get)** and / or **[$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post)**.

**[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** to load returned data.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Pixeler, i have two files: 1. index.php 2. process.php                   i want to redirect user to index page if user entered wrong answer. so i wrote this line in process.php:::   header("location:index.php?message=".$message);                      its redirecting but clearing all form fields in index.php.... so thats my problem.(I dont want to clear input values)